# Moving certain files to new location (and appending the datettime)

Tags: debian, mv

I have two Directories:

```
/routea/path/to/dir1
/routeb/path/to/dir2
```

in `dir1` I have some files:

```
file.name
file.name.1
file.name.2
file.name.3
```

(There may be more than the 4 files).
I need to move the files ending 1-3 to `dir2`

I tried (what I assumed was the obvious step) of:

```
mv /routea/path/to/dir1/file.name.* /routeb/path/to/dir2/
```

But that just tells me

```
mv: cannot stat `/routea/path/to/dir1/file.name.*': No such file or directory
```

To complicate matters, ideally I would like to add a timestamp to the end of each file as I move them, so I end up with something like `file.name.1.yyyymmddhhmmss`

can anyone point me in the right direction please. I assume I'll need to use some form of a loop to do this, but can't see how.

Comment: Is that the timestamp of the current time or of the last modification time of the files to be moved?

Comment: `mv /routea/path/to/dir1/file.name.* /routeb/path/to/dir2/` should have worked. Either you've made a typo or you've disabled globbing (with `set -f` with most bourne-like shells, `set +f` to re-enable).

Comment: the timestamp is just a way to make the filename unique, so either option would work. I also tried the `set +f` but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find dir1/ -name "file.name.[1-3]" -exec bash -c 'mv {} dir2/$(basename "{}").$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)' \;
```

Comment: cheers for that, it works a treat.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for examle with the for loop like the one below :

```
for f in /routea/path/to/dir1/file.name.? ; do fn=`echo $f | cut -d'/' -f6`;  mv $f /routeb/path/to/dir2/$fn.`date +%Y%m%d%H%M` ; done
```

The cut command must be customized based on how many subdirectories you have. Date is added also. Tested with bash on RedHat.
If you launch the command in the directory `/route/path/to/dir1/`, then you do not need the

```
fn=`echo $f | cut -d'/' -f6`;
```

part.

Comment: there are some subdirectories, but I'm not interested in them, does that make a difference? Also when I tried this (I'm adding `sudo` to the front) I get `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'do'`

Comment: it does make a difference where are you located (in which directory) when you launch the command. If you are launching the command from the directory where the files are, the for loop will return as a value only the name of the file. If you launch the command from another directory, the for loop will return the whole directory tree and the filename, and you have to cut the filename.

Comment: ok, I will be in the target directory `/routeb/path/to/dir2/` (or probably `/routeb/path`)

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv "/routea/path/to/dir1/(file.name.<1-3>)" "/routeb/path/to/dir2/\$1.$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
```